# how to harvest all files in one folder with wix

Tags: wix

I have the following requirement: I wish to harvest all files in one folder to my install packet, but the files in that folder may increase or decrease, how can i do it automatically? and if i have two file sources, i wish file in source 2 auto-overwrite file in source 1 with same file name, how can i do this?
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't include several file from Wix directly, but you can use a tool named "heat" to do it for you. Be careful it is not recommended to use it automatically on build.

Link to the [Doc](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/heat.htm).

I don't understand your second question.

Comment: i know "heat", but if the number of files in the folder is not stable, how can i pack them in my msi?

Comment: my second question is : for folder A and B, i wish to copy all the files in them to my install packet, but if a file "a.txt" exists in both A and B with different content, how can i select "a.txt" in B automatically to my MSI packet?

Comment: What does "not stable" mean? Does the number of files change during the build process, or just before it? Heat.exe will pick all the files in a folder you point it to: first build it can be 3 files, second build it can be 100 files, doesn't matter.

Comment: As for your second question, you'll have to apply XSLT transform to your harvested authoring to make it possible. Heat.exe has -t switch for this

Comment: thanks for your reply. i means, for example, if the folder contains the smiley icons for a im tool, some ued may add something new into the folder, what should i do? run heat.exe everytime befor auto-build?

Comment: and for xslt, can you give me some detail info about that? thanks

Comment: well, nothing special here. see help text of the heat.exe: you specify xslt transform in -t switch, and it does its job - xml in, xml out. No wix-specific things - just pure transformation, hence no limitations for you.

Comment: thanks, can you give me some advice on first question too?  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------i means, for example, if the folder contains the smiley icons for a im tool, some ued may add something new into the folder, what should i do? run heat.exe everytime befor auto-build?

Comment: Yep, why not? This is, of course, not recommended, I mean you should avoid as much of randomness as possible during your MSI package build.

Comment: The trouble then becomes that if you have some manual process for running heat, you're setting yourself up for the day when someone forgets to do it and then wonders why their recently-authored content isn't appearing in the MSI package. Far better to have heat do its stuff everytime so you can certain that everything that should be included is actually included. You could build some smarts into a Continuous Integration build to check for changes and automatically commit the updated .wxs if you were really worried about the performance hit of doing it in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can harvest all files in one folder even the number is not stable.

For example:

```
heat dir "src" -gg -sfrag -out src.wxs
```

This will harvest the sub folder "src" as a single fragment to the file src.wxs. You will then use `candle` and `light` to pack them into your msi.

If the number of files changes, just re-run `heat` and the src.wxs will be updated.