# Include all files in a specific directory into msi package

Tags: wix

I've got a directory containing multiple files that I want to include in my msi package build by a `Wix` project.

```
/database
/database/migration11.txt
/database/migration21.txt
/database/migration32.txt
```

Those files change often or there are new ones added, and I don't want to adapt my `Wix` file with every new migration file.

Basically I want to say in my `wxs` file *to include all files in the directory database* and upon installation put them in the directory `[INSTALLLOCATION]/database`.

Any way to achieve this?

**ADDED:**

Just found this workaround: [use HEAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5100898/220636) but I'm curious if there is another, recommended way.

Comment: Heat is quite a recommended way. It is a part of the toolset. There's also an external tool called Paraffin (http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/tags/Paraffin/default.aspx) widely used in the community. BTW, you should be careful with the automation. If you don't plan to change the contents of that folder extensively, it  might be better to generate a WiX file once, and include it into solution, and later on just modify it as the folder contents changes. More manual work, but more control. Trade-offs, as usual :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I thought not to use Heat because is seems [not to be recommended to use automatically in your built](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5100898/220636). But I'll check it out.

Comment: "Not recommended == be careful" in this case. If you have lots of files, you have little choice. As I mentioned, it's still a trade-off at some point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to harvest all files in one folder with wix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100505/how-to-harvest-all-files-in-one-folder-with-wix)

Answer (score 15):

You can use  task in your wixproj file:

```
<ItemGroup> 
... Your wxs files ...
<HarvestDirectory Include="$(variable)\YourDirectory\">
  <ComponentGroupName>CG_YOUR_GROUP</ComponentGroupName>
  <DirectoryRefId>DIR_REFERENCE</DirectoryRefId>
  <AutogenerateGuids>false</AutogenerateGuids>
  <GenerateGuidsNow>false</GenerateGuidsNow>
  <SuppressUniqueIds>true</SuppressUniqueIds>
  <SuppressCom>true</SuppressCom>
  <SuppressRegistry>true</SuppressRegistry>
  <SuppressRootDirectory>true</SuppressRootDirectory>
  <PreprocessorVariable>var.Property_Preprocessor</PreprocessorVariable>
</HarvestDirectory>
</ItemGroup>
```

This task calls Heat during the build. Hope this helps you.

Comment: What is HarvestDirectory? Is there an extension that requires this? Where do you put this tag, exactly? Please provide a working example.

Comment: How does this translate to the actual wxs file? If you're not using wixproj?

Answer (score 5):

If anyone still needs this, [here](https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/wix-example-harvest-directory) is a sample of HarvestDirector with wixproj. Thanks to [DavidEGrayson](https://github.com/DavidEGrayson).

Comment: This should be a comment.